# Plastic cage around LED GU10 socket

Tags: light-fixture, led

We bought a new house in the UK in 2011.  Most of the lighting is GU10 LED bulbs although a couple of rooms have GU10 halgens, which I'm happily replacing with LEDs as they burn out.

A couple of the already-installed LEDs have now gone as well.  When I've tried to replace them, the GU10 socket has a plastic cage attached (see picture, with replacement bulb).  This means the bulbs I've been buying don't fit, as they are slightly shorter than the existing LEDs, and the rim of the bulb stops the contacts from engaging with the socket.

I haven't been able to find replacement bulbs that fit (I've bought Philips Master LEDspot MVs) and I can't see how the cage can be removed without unwiring the socket completely.

Any ideas for how I can fit a new bulb, or even what the purpose of the cage is, would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the cage is there to stop insulation from touching the bulb.

Comment: Garbage proprietary GU-10 socket that forces you to buy the manufacturer's replacement bulbs. And if the manufacturer goes out of business...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just cutting the cage off using an ordinary pair of scissors.  Haven't had any problems since.

Comment: As long as you don't remove anything above ceiling level you should be fine. My guess on the original purpose is that it might've been to either (1) prevent someone or something from touching the extremely hot halogen bulb (less of an issue with LEDs, which run much cooler), or (2) cast a unique striped light pattern, if the OEM bulbs aren't the parabolic reflector type.